# How do familiars get created?

Tags: madoka-magica

> After eating a few humans ― approximately four or five according to
>   Kyoko in episode 5 ― they will grow into witches themselves.

---

> familiars are "projections of the magical girl's heart before she became a witch".

When a magical girl falls into despair, her soul gem turns into a grief seed, which makes her a witch. What does "projections of the magical girl's heart" mean? Does it mean a magical girl can become more than one witch? Also, how does this affect the universal entropy?

Answer (score 9):

> When a magical girl falls into despair, her soul gem turns into a grief seed, which makes her a witch.

Sounds about right. Fun times all round! Good old 'Dokes.

> What does "projections of the magical girl's heart" mean?

Madoka is quite meta in it's Magic sometimes. Consider Wishes, which just break **all** laws **ever**, by Kyuubey's word. The exact mechanics beetween Witches and Familiars aren't touched on much beyond they're some kind of life cycle, but we can infer some things.

- "Projections of the magical girl's heart **before she became a witch.**" Since that's a one-way trip, witches would seem to have a finite pool of experience to base Familiars on.
- Witches maintain barriers to protect themselves and entrap victims.
- Familiars are a division of a Witch's essence who, after consuming several humans will grow into a Witch with their own barrier.

Witches seem to be creatures of emotion, given that they're born from grief, and their very appearance is a complex cocktail of the Girl's emotions, desires and fears. This makes the line about "projections of the heart" make more sense.

I imagine the process to be something like this.

- Magical Girl becomes a Witch. Her appearance and powers are defined by her experiences prior.
- Witch feels one of her remembered emotions in her essence
- The emotion is so strong it is "divided out of the essence" and becomes it's own, autonomous being with it's own essence, based on that emotion.
- Feeding on humans develops the familiar into a Witch somehow, at which point it can erect it's own barrier and become truly autonomous.

And an example:

- Charlotte is a Witch. Her Magical Girl self loved cheese.
- Charlotte wants cheese.
- Charlotte **really** wants cheese.
- Charlotte wants cheese **so hard**, that a little bit of **"WANT CHEESE"** pushes out of "her", subdivides from her essence and drops off.
- Naturally it's entirely **"WANT CHEESE"** and is thus single-minded and weak.
- It consumes a person. This somehow grows it's essence a little. It's a little smarter and stronger.
- Repeat this until it's grown enough to handle a barrier. At this point, it can leave the vicinity of it's "parent" safely and can protect itself as a fully grown Witch.

Although, this does raise the question: Does every familiar bother hunting and killing people? How fast is their growth rate? The Witches in the series never seem to handle more than 10-20 people at once, maximum, so it may not be that viable, considering the Witch must need feeding too. Food for thought. (haha)

> Does it mean a magical girl can become more than one witch?

By the logic we've been presented with, I can see no reason why not. Though, there's no mention of whether a Familiar grows into it's parent Witch, or something else. It does raise questions about "Witch Farming" as a viable tactic though.

Kyouko's "Wait around until they become Witches" seems a very passive route. Why not directly feed your Familiars humans if you *really* don't care? Looks like the goodness of a girl's heart is the only thing keeping us safe. Fitting, non?

---

**Note:**

From discussion in the comments, it's become clear that we don't really know if Familiar!Witches *actually* drop Grief Seeds apart from these lines from Kyouko

> "You just have to wait until it eats four or five people and becomes a witch. That way, you'll be able to get a Grief Seed from it. Why would you want to slaughter the chicken before it lays any eggs?"

Yes, Kyouko *thinks* they do, but we never actually see it happen. Thus, it makes the next section only relevant if they do. If they don't, everything's fine and there's no imbalance in the first place, so potato-patato.

---

> Also, how does this affect the universal entropy?

The same way the rest of the series does, this doesn't necessarily change anything.

Initially thinking about this, yes, I got a little freaked if you could potentially get fifteen witches where you had one, and that'd definitely throw something somewhere down the line off.

But when you get down to it, there are a few points of information we can use.

- Magical Girls have been around for a looooong time. Consider the historical ones we see for sure. In fact, Kyuubey flat out states we'd still be in caves without his kind, so that kind of dates them. Though, if you trust his word is another matter entirely.
- Only with "The Most Powerful Witch" will Incubators have offset Entropy for any reasonable amount, and she was *ludicrously powerful*. I won't reason about it here for plot's sake but she's a complete fluke is my point.

So, threading this together.

If Magical Girls have been around for a long time and only now, with this completely, universally, OP Witch, will we actually make a dent, we can infer that the Entropy paid back for a "normal" witch isn't actually that much. Kyuubey can harp on about his "tremendous amount of energy" all he wants, but from the looks of things they aren't really doing a whole lot.

The way Kyuubey treats the girls, even apart from his alien detachedness, would suggest that they're disposable to him. And they are, because this entire scheme is ultra-long-term. He has a quota to reach, yes. But his deadline is *literally* the death of the Universe. A girl here or there, a few witches, it doesn't matter. Thousands, millions, now they might matter. But the impact of the average individual Girl or Witch doesn't seem to. Thank you for making me logic out this horrifying new revelation, I really enjoyed it. :)

Thus:

- Normal Witches are worthless in the grand scheme of things, since we've been fighting them for years and Kyuubey makes no mention of progress.
- Entropy would need many multiples of the time Magical Girls have been around to even begin to be repaid.
- So you can have ten, fifteen witches from one girl and it's still chump change.

And yes, this means there are ten, fifteen Witches in the locality now. But all Kyuubey has to do to rebalance the teams is lie to three, four little girls. And we all know how good he is at that!

Comment: About the witch farm. It doesn't seem possible since not every witch drops a soul gem and it looks like only the mother witch has a soul gem, familar based witches only posses the power of barrier it suppose. Good one btw.

Comment: @Entei I like the idea of Soul Gem == Grief Seed, thus only "Mother" Witches have one. Though, Kyouko's line in episode 5 is "You just have to wait until it eats four or five people and becomes a witch. That way, you'll be able to get a Grief Seed from it. Why would you want to slaughter the chicken before it lays any eggs?" It's ripe for retconning if they wanna do that, but as it stands that's all the info we have to go on.

Comment: It seemed to me that information is incorrect if you look from her point of view. They know *some* witches contain grief seed but they don't know which. They just think it randomly drops so it's reasonable to let them kill 5 people if there is a chance of greif seed to drop from the characters perspective, even though they're wrong.

Comment: Also, adding to the entropy Answer: Another explanation is that despite how "Tremendous" Witch energy is, the Universe may use many times that amount in the time it takes to destroy a Witch. So in the grand scheme, it's still not worth a whole lot. _Another_ explanation is Entropy has been in a tentative balance, with Girls adding and Universe subtracting, maybe we've been hovering around like, 40% Total Energy forever? The events of the series could then push that to like, 400%, creating free energy for everyone and releasing Incubators from their duties (for a time)

Comment: @Entei You're right, there's no reason to take Kyouko's word for it that that's how it works. Yeah, she's been around a while, but the whole Magical Girl thing is a bundle of lies to begin with, so who do we trust? Kyuubey, by definition, _can't lie_, but he **can** _not tell the whole truth_. Really this whole thing hasn't been nailed down enough in-canon to do anything but speculate.

Answer (score 0):

The "projections of the heart" could mean a few things. The interpretation that I get from the wiki, is that the familiars are based off strong feelings. These can be regular everyday emotions or they can be a strong like towards something. I.E. Charlotte desires a certain type of cheese above everything else so her familiar Pyotr only duty is to search for cheese. As for how they are created not much is really stated. One can assume that the familiar is born alongside the witch or the witch creates the familiar using the "projections". ref([Madoka Magica Characters](https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Characters))